# How to display the frames of several pictures as an animation on loop using React Native

Tags: react-native

I have several frames of an animation. I want to display the animation on a loop. I've read:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated
https://blog.bitsrc.io/making-animations-in-react-native-the-simplified-guide-6580f961f6e8
And I have tried implementing:
https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-animations-using-the-animated-api-ebe8e0669fae
But none of them cover multiple frames of animation and how to loop through them using simple code. I'm sure what I need to do is v simple but these tutorials are over-whelming.

Here's some code I'm using:
Just before the render

```
Images: [
        { id: 1, src: './assets//frame1.png', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
        { id: 2, src: './assets//frame2.png', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
        { id: 3, src: './assets//frame3.png', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
        { id: 4, src: './assets//frame4.png', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
        { id: 5, src: './assets//frame32.png', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },

      ]

render() {
const items = this.state.Images.map((item, key) =>
    <Image key={item.id}>{item.name}</Image>

...

<View>
  {items}
</View>
```

That doesn't work - objects are not valid as a react child...

How would I simply display the first image of that array in the first place but then make it loop though each image (creating an animation).

Can anyone provide a simple block of code that demonstrates how to cycle/loop through several .png files in an assets folder as an animation on screen?

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed **Interpolation** through **Opacity**.

- Just modify the data array like your Image array and display the images inside the Animating View.

> Iterate through your Image array and set the opacity Values.

```
const data = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink', 'red'];
this.animations = new Animated.Value(0);
this.opacity = [];
data.map((item, index) => {
  this.opacity.push(
    this.animations.interpolate({
      inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
      outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
    }),
  );
});
```

- Now this.opacity array will contain the corresponding opacity values for each item.

> Now start the loop. *(here I am using 2 sec to animate from one image to other )*

```
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(this.animations, {
    toValue: length - 1,
    duration: 2000 * length,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }),
).start();
```

> Set opacity for each item inside the render

```
const opacity = this.opacity[index];
```

## **Full Code** (example)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Animated, Easing} from 'react-native';

const data = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink', 'red'];

const length = data.length;

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.animations = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.opacity = [];
    data.map((item, index) => {
      this.opacity.push(
        this.animations.interpolate({
          inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
        }),
      );
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.animations, {
        toValue: length - 1,
        duration: 2000 * length,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ).start();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {data.map((item, index) => {
          const opacity = this.opacity[index];
          return (
            <Animated.View
              style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor: item, opacity}]}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  item: {
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

I hope it will help you.